# Can't use userInfo() function from Node JS v10.14.1 os module

Tags: node.js, node-modules

The code in which I'm getting the error is:

```
console.log('Starting app.js...');
const fs = require('fs');
const os = require('os');
var user = os.userInfo();
fs.appendFile('Abhisht.txt', 'Hii ${user.username}!');
```

The command and the error I'm getting is:

```
C:\Users\Abhisht Srivastava\Desktop\nodeapp>node app.js
Starting app.
fs.js:129
  throw new ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK();
  ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function
at maybeCallback (fs.js:129:9)
at Object.appendFile (fs.js:1210:14)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Abhisht Srivastava\Desktop\nodeapp      \app.js:8:4)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:741:12)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:285:19)
```

I'm using node v10.14.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a callback.

You have a file operation and a file operation requires a callback.

At line 5, after the completion of file operation, you have to add the call back method.

```
console.log('Starting app.js...');
const fs = require('fs');
const os = require('os');
var user = os.userInfo();
fs.appendFile('Abhisht.txt', `Hii ${user.username}!`, (err) => {
    console.log('Done');
});
```

Please check the [doc](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_path_data_options_callback) for more options.
Also the single quote `'` needs to be replaced by backtick `` ` ``.

Comment: and also the `'` should be `\`` for desired behaviour for OP.